# Is this the best way to pull friends from Facebook?

Tags: objective-c, facebook

Is this a good way to get a complete friend list with UID and name and Pic URL?

NSString *q0 = @"SELECT uid, name, pic FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me())";

Is this a good way to get friend checkins, and details of friend in those checkins? (Query done via fql.multiquery)

NSString *q0 = @"SELECT uid, name, pic FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me())";
NSString *q1 = @"SELECT checkin_id, author_uid, page_id, coords FROM checkin WHERE author_uid IN (SELECT uid FROM #q0)";
NSString *q2 = @"SELECT name, page_id FROM place WHERE page_id IN (SELECT page_id FROM #q1)";

Comment: Please add code tags for the code, makes it much more readable

Comment: This this two separate questions in one?

Comment: I'm sorry DMCS - it is just one question I was writting it fast:   NSString *q0 = @"SELECT uid, name, pic FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me())"; NSString *q1 = @"SELECT checkin_id, author_uid, page_id, coords FROM checkin WHERE author_uid IN (SELECT uid FROM #q0)"; NSString *q2 = @"SELECT name, page_id FROM place WHERE page_id IN (SELECT page_id FROM #q1)";

Answer (score 0):

SELECT uid,name,pic FROM user WHERE uid IN(SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me());